# Unexpected return from initial read: Out of Recources, buffersize 0

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10, So I turned on my computer I got this error:

[this the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T84tq.png)

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Out of Recources, buffersize 0
Failed to load image : Out of Resources
start_image() returned Out of Resources
```

and then windows booted automatically.

How to solve this error and make  Ubuntu booted automatically like before. Thanks, in advance

Comment: you have enough disk space on our ubuntu permission?

Comment: I used 2 disk, nvme for ubuntu and ssd for windows